# vb.net - WebRequest & WebClient fast from Windows10 but slow on MS Server 2012

Tags: vb.net, performance, webclient, windows-server-2012, webrequest

vb.net WebRequest and WebClient..DownloadFile calls are fast (2 seconds) when run on my laptop (Windows10) but slow (2 minutes) when run on MS Server 2012.

I've taken all advice I can find on setting Proxy to null/nothing, have watched HTTP requests with 'Microsoft Network Monitor' for calls and responses and now wonder about MS Server 2012 settings..

Can anyone recommend MS Server 2012 firewall or other settings I can change to try to alleviate this performance difference?

Thanks.

Comment: This may do better on another SE site. SO is for programming related issues. I'm not sure which site to suggest however. Maybe [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: thanks - I didn't stop to think about that...

Comment: Also tried on Windows 7 Pro and takes 2 mins per call.